# Write ecto schema to csv file in elixir?

Tags: csv, elixir, phoenix-framework

Hi I have Person schema in elixir like this

```
[
  %Texting.Contact.Person{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "people">,
    email: nil,
    name: "John",
    phone_number: "13334445555",
    phonebook: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :phonebook is not loaded>,
    phonebook_id: 60,
    previous_phonebook_id: 60,
    subscribed: true,
    updated_at: ~N[2018-09-22 14:36:04.788163],
    user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
    user_id: 54
  },
  %Texting.Contact.Person{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "people">,
    email: nil,
    name: "Rhee",
    phone_number: "14443335555",
    phonebook: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :phonebook is not loaded>,
    phonebook_id: 60,
    previous_phonebook_id: 60,
    subscribed: true,
    updated_at: ~N[2018-09-22 14:36:13.671479],
    user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
    user_id: 54
  }
]
```

And I want to save this to csv file format.So I did this

```
def write!(people) do
    file = File.open("contacts.csv", [:write, :utf8])
    people
    |> Enum.map(&Map.from_struct(&1))
    |> Enum.map(&CSV.encode(&1, headers: [:name, :phone_number]))
    |> Enum.map(&IO.write(file, &1))
end
```

but I got an error like this

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for #Function<62.51129937/2 in Stream.transform/3>. This protocol is implemented for: Atom, BitString, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Ecto.Date, Ecto.DateTime, Ecto.Time, Float, Floki.Selector, Floki.Selector.AttributeSelector, Floki.Selector.Combinator, Floki.Selector.Functional, Floki.Selector.PseudoClass, Integer, List, NaiveDateTime, Postgrex.Copy, Postgrex.Query, Postgrex.Stream, Time, URI, Version, Version.Requirement
    (elixir) /home/ubuntu/bob/tmp/0a92cc555e2418d1b56e3b10e5321a85/elixir/lib/elixir/lib/string/chars.ex:3: String.Chars.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) /home/ubuntu/bob/tmp/0a92cc555e2418d1b56e3b10e5321a85/elixir/lib/elixir/lib/string/chars.ex:22: String.Chars.to_string/1
    (elixir) lib/io.ex:553: IO.write/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1314: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
```

What I want to do is save only name and phone_number field to csv file format.
How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using https://hex.pm/packages/csv or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/csv/CSV.html#encode/2), `CSV.encode/2` takes a list of list of strings and doesn't have the option you tried to use.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def write!(people) do
  people
  |> Stream.map(&[&1.name, &1.phone_number])
  |> CSV.encode()
  |> Enum.into(File.stream!("contacts.csv"))
end
```

The `Enum.map` creates a list of list of strings which is then encoded and streamed into `contacts.csv`.

To add a header line at the top, you can use `Stream.concat/2` to prepend the header line:

```
def write!(people) do
  [["name", "phone_number"]]
  |> Stream.concat(people |> Stream.map(&[&1.name, &1.phone_number]))
  |> CSV.encode()
  |> Enum.into(File.stream!("contacts.csv"))
end
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but I got an error. `code` ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in File.normalize_modes/2

Comment: The following arguments were given to File.normalize_modes/2:
    
        # 1
        "contacts.csv" 
    
        # 2
        true
    
    Attempted function clauses (showing 6 out of 6):
    
        defp normalize_modes([:utf8 | rest], binary?)
        defp normalize_modes([:read_ahead | rest], binary?)
        defp normalize_modes([mode | rest], _binary?) when mode === :char_list or mode === :charlist
        defp normalize_modes([mode | rest], binary?)
        defp normalize_modes([], true)

Comment: Sorry the `File.stream!` line was completely wrong. Can you try the edited code?

Comment: and I don't have to use IO.write function to write to file?

Comment: Nope, `File.stream!` opens a stream and `Enum.into` writes to it. No need to manually call `IO.write`.

Comment: Oh I see. It works! what if I want to add headers "name" and "phone_number" to that csv file. I tried while calling CSV.encode(headers: [:name, :phone_number]) but got an error like this..  ** (BadMapError) expected a map, got: ["John", "13334445555"]